# Change color of markers for each KML Layer?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have many different KML layers on a Google Map (v3).  Random colors of markers were assigned to each set of markers.  I would like to be able to control this, however.

So far, this is what I have:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);    
var kmlLayerOptions = { preserveViewport: true, suppressInfoWindows: true };    
var Layer1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://myurl.com/1.xml', kmlLayerOptions);
Layer1.setMap(map);
var Layer2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://myurl.com/2.xml', kmlLayerOptions);
Layer2.setMap(map);
```

I need to be able to say I want Layer 1 to use blue markers and layer 2 to use red markers, but I can't seem to figure this out.

From what I can tell, there is no way to do this with the kmlLayerOptions, which is where it would seem like it would happen, so I don't see where else I could logically make this change other than directly on the layer object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change it with KmlLayer (at least currently, you could create an [Enhancement request to add the functionality](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/)).

You can do it with FusionTablesLayers (import your KML into FusionTables, then use either the User Interface to set the icons or dynamic styling in the Google Maps API v3 (assuming you need less than 5 different icons, and the ones you want are available in FusionTables).

A final option would be to edit the existing KML to use the icons you want.

Answer (score 1):

The KmlLayer renders according to the styling in the KML document itself, and you cannot override this in any layer options.

If you don't want to modify the KML itself, you could use a third party library such as http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/ to render the KML on the clientside rather than having Google's servers render it, and this would give you the ability to override the rendering defaults.